# Codility Leader Algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am attempting the Codility 'Leader' question in JavaScript.

The question is as follows:

> An array `A` consisting of `N` integers is given. The dominator of array `A` is the value that occurs in more than half of the elements of `A`.
>
> For example, consider array `A` such that
>
> ```
> A[0] = 3    A[1] = 4    A[2] =  3
> A[3] = 2    A[4] = 3    A[5] = -1
> A[6] = 3    A[7] = 3
> ```
>
> The dominator of `A` is 3 because it occurs in 5 out of 8 elements of `A` (namely in `>` those with indices 0, 2, 4, 6 and 7) and 5 is more than a half of 8.
>
> Write a function `function solution(A);`  that, given an array `A` consisting of `N` integers, returns index of any element of array `A` in which the dominator of `A` occurs. The function should return −1 if array `A` does not have a dominator.
>
> For example, given array `A` such that
>
> ```
> A[0] = 3    A[1] = 4    A[2] =  3
> A[3] = 2    A[4] = 3    A[5] = -1
> A[6] = 3    A[7] = 3
> ```
>
> the function may return 0, 2, 4, 6 or 7, as explained above.
>
> Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
>
> `N` is an integer within the range `[0..100,000];`
> and each element of array `A` is an integer within the range `[−2,147,483,648..2,147,483,647]`.

My answer is below:

```
function solution(A) {
    const length = A.length
    if (length > 100000) return -1
    const counters = new Array(length).fill(0)
    const negativeCounters = new Array(length).fill(0)
    for (i=0; i < length; i++){
        if (A[i] < -2147483648 || A[i] > 2147483647) return -1
        if (A[i] > -1){
            counters[A[i]] = counters[A[i]] + 1
            if (counters[A[i]] > (length / 2)) return i
        } else {
            negativeCounters[A[i] * -1]  =  negativeCounters[A[i] * -1] + 1
            if (negativeCounters[A[i] * -1] > (length / 2)) return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

This is failing the correctness tests although I have tried a variety of inputs with which it succeeds. The Codility evaluation doesn't list the test input so I can't find input that is breaking the algorithm.

Can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: question: if the array goes like `[0..1]`, then max length is 2. If the array goes like `[0..100,000];`, shouldn't max length be 100,001 ? You're restricting that case in your first if

Comment: Does the failing case give you any output? It is possible that you are running out of memory, allocating two arrays of size, possibly 100K each

Comment: @Gonzalo.- haha i was worrying about the same thing, i think not because the question specifies WITHIN the range 0 to 100000 members so 100001 would cause return.

Comment: @sinanspd heres some output: on SMALL_TEST .. WRONG ANSWER, got -1, but dominator exists, for example on position 8, on SMALL_NON_DENOMINATOR.. got -1, but dominator exists, for example on position 0, on MEDIUM_RANDOM (random test with dominator, N = 10,000).. got -1, but dominator exists, for example on position 9. This is the crux of the problem im having the output isnt very helpful

Comment: @NicoSchertler this works fine in JavaScript: `a = new Array(3); a[2147483647] = 4; console.log(a.length, a[2147483647])` because arrays are associative in JS. However, trying to increment a value that hasn't been initialised to zero might not work so well.

Comment: Happy Machine, you might want to take a look at [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm)

Comment: @Nico did you pick up that I have two arrays one for negative numbers?

Comment: Sorry, did not realize that this was JavaScript. Never mind then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to some comments and one answer, in fact using an array of counters in JavaScript works fine. This is because arrays in JavaScript are associative objects. One problem with your code is that it fails to initialise to zero counters whose key/index is greater than the initial counters array length.

Here is code that gets 100% on all of Codility's measures:

```
function solution(A) {
    const arr = []
    for (let i=0; i<A.length; i++){
      if (!arr[A[i]])
        arr[A[i]] = 1
      else
        arr[A[i]]++
      if (arr[A[i]] > A.length/2)
        return i
    }
    return -1
}
```

Comment: ah .. doh. Of course, i didn't think of that i was thinking of the array length as the bounds of the integers.. very silly. Amazing, thanks so much : ) I hoped this approach would work

Comment: But how is this going to work on negative integers

Comment: @NtwariClaranceLiberiste try it, log it, and learn :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use an array with that big range of values (the array for the positive values would need a length of 2,147,483,648). You should use a map or in js you can use an object. I hacked something together, not very elegant, but it passes all tests:

```
function solution(A) {
    const map = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        const key = '' + A[i]
        map[key] = key in map ? map[key] + 1 : 1
        if (map[key] > A.length / 2)
            return i
    }
    return -1
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect when it comes to JavaScript. Please see my answer.

Comment: @גלעדברקן  Well I still get 100%. If I say `let arr = []; arr[15] = 12; console.log(arr);` it will print out 16 values and `arr.length` is 16. So it is not completely wrong. Maybe it doesn't use all the storage, but I'm right about the length.

Comment: It just doesn't feel clean. The length is wrong. What would you do if you wanted to iterate over all values which are defined? Maybe it works for this case, but I don't like it.

Comment: I agree. It's not clean and in general it seems like misappropriating the use of an array. I was trying to point out that in this case, it may not have been the cause for the code failure for the OP.